# react-select testing same name labels using jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-select

I'm trying to test react select  with react testing library and there is **multiple labels with the same name**

```
<div>

<div>
<label htmlFor={'state'} >State</label>
<Select inputId={'state'} {...stuff}/>
</div>

<div>
<label htmlFor={'state'} >State</label>
<Select inputId={'state'} {...stuff}/>
</div>


</div>
```

I'm using npm package **selectEvent** to test

```
selectEvent.select(getByLabelText('State'), ['Alabama']);
selectEvent.select(getByLabelText('State'), ['Alaska']);
```

Although it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  const [firstLabel, secondLabel] = getAllByLabelText('State');
    await act(async () => {
      fireEvent.focus(firstLabel);
      fireEvent.keyDown(firstLabel, {
        key: 'ArrowDown',
        keyCode: 40,
        code: 40,
      });

      await waitFor(() => {
        fireEvent.click(getByText('Alabama'));
      });

      fireEvent.focus(secondLabel);
      fireEvent.keyDown(secondLabel, {
        key: 'ArrowDown',
        keyCode: 40,
        code: 40,
      });

      await waitFor(() => {
        fireEvent.click(getByText('Alaska'));
      });
    });
```